# How to launch Applet in Firefox 52+ without Java-Browser-PlugIn?

Tags: html, firefox, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

Cause Java-Browser-PlugIn will become deprecated and NPAPI meanwhile is disabled in most browsers I try to figure out how to launch our applets in other ways.

This code works fine with JRE 1.8.0_141 (32 Bit) and Internet Explorer 11 (32 Bit, Java-PlugIn deactivated), but no launch with Firefox 54 (NoESR, 32 Bit, no Java-PlugIn installed).

`http://localhost:8888/startTestApplet.htm`

**html file: startTestAppplet.htm**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>TestApplet HTML-Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
TestApplet Start
<hr>
<APPLET jnlp_href="TestApplet.jnlp" width="800" height="500" >
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**jnlp file: TestApplet.jnlp**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8888/" href="TestApplet.jnlp" >
    <information>
        <title>WebStart JNLP TestApplet</title>
    </information>
    <security>
      <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="TestApplet.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="TestApplet"
         main-class="testPackage.TestApplet"
         width="800"
         height="300">
     </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Using IE Java starts with java security warning and opens the applet embedded in my html-page.

With FF no hint, that Java starts and the html page remains empty.

But with both browsers it is posssible, to launch the jnlp file directly:

```html
http://localhost:8888/TestApplet.jnlp
```

In both cases the applet opens after a java security warning outside of the invoking browser in an own Java applet window.

Don't understand what's going on here. Why the applet (or the Java software) can't be startet in Firefox by the APPLET tag with jnlp_href attribute in my html file? Syntax fault in html? Bug in Firefox? Maybe expectable consequence of disabling NPAPI in Firefox 52+? Are there other solutions to start our applets via html file? Thank You for reading.

Comment: *"Cause Java-Browser-PlugIn will become deprecated and NPAPI meanwhile is disabled in most browsers I try to figure out how to launch our applets in other ways."* The only other way is to provide a direct link to the JNLP that might result in the applet ending up free floating on the desktop (once the user clicks the link and allows the prompts etc.). A free floating applet cannot interact with the web page.

Comment: Our applets do not interact with the invoking web page. But they get parameters from the invoking page for connection and login to a database.

Comment: Parameters can be provided to a JWS launched applet in the [JNLP file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/migrating-java-applets-jnlp.htm#JSDPG-GUID-6B65096D-49F3-4AE2-B9ED-F8137A9B4D9E).

Comment: This could be a way, if I cannot find a solution for the access problem of Firefox 52+ via "<APPLET jnlp_ref=..." - thanks!